# Why does the Moon - which is grey - appear white to us even at daytime?

Tags: optics, visible-light, astronomy, moon

The color of the Moon as viewed more closely, is grey. But when we see it in the sky it appears white to us. Why?

Although this question has some answers here: [Why is the surface of the Moon white?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/193585/why-is-the-surface-of-the-moon-white) (which is **not** asking the same question, but is rather asking “what **materials** give the Moon its white color, as you can see that it’s tagged “Material Science”),  none of the answers really concern “why does it appear white during **the day**”.

One answer briefly mentions the daytime scenario:

> When you see the moon "by itself", brighter than anything else in the night sky **(or brighter than the blue sky in the day)** our brain says "that's white".

But that doesn’t quite answer the question. Because although it’s true that the Moon is brighter than the daytime sky, the difference is way too small to make the grey moon appear white. Here is an image of the Moon with a black background and with a (near) sky blue background:[image: moon against black & blue backgrounds]

Although it may be debatable whether the Moon looks white in the upper picture, I don’t thing it’s valid for the lower picture.

And why does the Moon look white even when compared to surrounding clouds?

Edit:

I came up with an answer, but I'm afraid to post it as an answer until I have some people agreeing with me.

It's probably for the same reason we don't see the dark side of the moon neither at day nor at night. For some reason, we can't see **darkness** of outer space (at least not at daytime), but only **brightness**. So only the white part of the grey reaches our eyes, while the black part of it doesn't. Probably that reason is that our sky color is already taking in account the background blackness of outer space which is present behind the entire sky.

I would really appreciate if you can share your knowledge or opinion on that answer.

Comment: If you see really detailed high resolution images of the moon you won't generally see just gray surface up there.

Comment: Why do you think the Moon should be a different colour during the day? This isn't a question about physics.

Comment: @ProfRob Because the only reason (given in the link above) it looks white is because we see it compared to the dark sky, which is not a valid reason for daytime.

Comment: I would read all the answers. The Moon looks grey because it has a broad spectrum. That's where the physics ends. You are asking about physiology and neuroscience.

Comment: And by grey I mean "grey" to the eye. The spectrum is not grey as detailed in answers to that question.

Comment: @ProfRob I'm perfectly okay with the Moon looking grey, what bothers me is why it looks **white**.

Comment: @ProfRob please see my edit in the question.

Comment: This is a human perception question, not a physics question, It seems that humans have a limited "white point compensation" built in. I am not well-read on the subject, but there are cases where a person has had cataracts (which shift color perception) removed, their perception of white takes some measurable time to shift back. Semi-random link ( https://jov.arvojournals.org/article.aspx?articleid=2474937 )